# Modify the date popup to only accept special days

Tags: javascript, datetime

I may need your help please. I have installed the "Date" module and using it with the date popup (datepicker). I need to have the popup just accepting Wednesdays and Fridays as dates.

Can anybody give me some help on this issue?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Just use jQuery and it's beforeShowDay attribute to check out if a date should be valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Date Restrictions](https://drupal.org/project/date_restrictions) in conjunction with [Weekdays](https://drupal.org/project/weekdays) to acomplish this.

Just download both projects and enable weekdays_date_restrictions module. Then edit the date field and go to "More settings and values" > "Date Restrictions" > "Allowed values" > Choose restriction type: weekdays.